# How to add existing project into Geany

Tags: c++, linux, geany

I have an existing C++ project which is built with Gnu Make. I want to develop the source under Geany but am unable find a way to import it.

Answer (score 9):

I know this i a rather old question, but it was first hit on my search for the exact question. Since I have figured it out now, I wanted to give an answer for future searchers.

One should create a new project. Select a name for the project, select a location for the project file, e.g. the root of the project directory and the the root of the project directory. That's it.

But - the documents tab is confusing, so I suggest installing a file browser plugin, by selecting `Tools` -> `Plugin Manager` and then select the plugin `File Browser`. This adds a tab that will enable browsing the files in the project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to import your project.

In geany go to **"Project/New"** and you'll be able to create a new project. Select a name for your project, select a file to save its settings and select the base directory where your source files are.

Then you'll be able to build to project with **"Build/Make"**. It will run make within the base directory you selected. You can customise the build commands if you go to **"Build/Set build commands"**.

Comment: This doesn't work. Adding an existing base path ignores all existing files in that path.